# Apigee JavaScript resource output running Cloud Code emulator?

Tags: apigee, google-cloud-code

I'm writing Apigee JavaScript Policy Resources using the VS Code Cloud Code plugin and can't locate the `print` statement output- is it available while running the Apigee (Docker) emulator?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` output is not available in the Apigee local development emulator, it is only available using Debug or Trace in the actual Apigee product.

To work around this I've written a couple of helper functions that log to the `context` and then dump the logs to the Response header:

```
function logMsg(msg) {
   var index = context.getVariable("logger.index");
   if (index == null) {
       index = 1;
   }
   context.setVariable("logger.logMsg-" + index, msg);
   index = index + 1;
   context.setVariable("logger.index", index);
}

// Call this function during Response processing
function logsToResponseHeader() {
    var index = context.getVariable("logger.index");
    if (index == null) {
        context.proxyResponse.headers['Z-Log-0'] = 'logger.index == null';
        return
    }

    context.proxyResponse.headers['Z-Log-0'] = 'logger.index == ' + index + ' type: ' + typeof (index);
    for (var i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        var msg = context.getVariable("logger.logMsg-" + i);
        if (msg == null) {
            context.proxyResponse.headers['Z-Log-' + i] = 'Null msg';
        } else {
            context.proxyResponse.headers['Z-Log-' + i] = msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output from `curl -v`:

```
< Z-Log-0: logger.index == 11 type: number
< Z-Log-1: Trace-Context-Request: enter
< Z-Log-2: Trace-Context-Request: exit
< Z-Log-3: Trace-Context-Response: enter
< Z-Log-4: WARN: null value for TraceEndTimestamp: 
< Z-Log-5: RequestParentID: 
< Z-Log-6: ParentID: 769db5b4
< Z-Log-7: TraceID: 9b5c3406fdd0d275
< Z-Log-8: TraceFlags: 01
< Z-Log-9: parentStartTime: 1640441735345
< Z-Log-10: Trace-Context-Response: exit
```